# LOOPBACK Modify another model inside a hook

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

I want to insert new data in Event model when the property "code" in Transaction model is equal to 3

```
 module.exports = function(Transaction) {
    Transaction.observe('before save', function(ctx, next) {
        if(ctx.data.code == 3){
          //How to access and insert data in Event model ?
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an Event model with a function to insert newData. Just reference the model. For ex:

```
var eventModel = require('pathtoEventModel');  

module.exports = function(Transaction) {
Transaction.observe('before save', function(ctx, next) {
    if(ctx.data.code == 3){
       eventModel.saveNewData(ctxBeingNewData,function(response,next){
       //manipulate as per your wish.
       })
    }
```

});
};

Comment: I tried require('event.js'), require('event'), require('common/models/event.js'), require('common/models/event') but get Error: Cannot find module 'event'

Comment: I appreciate your answer, however (as previous comment) couldn't get it work just by a silly error, after @Daniel 's answer point me to use `./model`, the `require` function works, but I'm stuck in model's function part (`saveNewData`, _eventModel.saveNewData is not a funcion_) although the function is already declared . I uploaded the code to GitHub just in case you want to give another valued help [link](https://github.com/leojparra/learning-loopback)

Answer (score 1):

this works for me. it's just like what @Sunil Lama said but I use loopback.getModel additionally

#### server.js

```
const loopback = require('loopback');
const ModelInst = require('./model-instnace');
boot(app, __dirname, function (err) {
   if (err) throw err;
   ModelInst.event = (loopback.getModel('event'));
};
```

#### model-instance.js

```
const ModelInst = {
    ...
    event:null
    ...
}
```

#### model.js

```
const models = require('model-instnace Path');
module.exports = function(Transaction) {
    Transaction.observe('before save', function(ctx, next) {
        if(ctx.data.code == 3){
            models.event.insertNewDate('blah');
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me

```
module.exports = function(Transaction) {
  Transaction.observe('before save', function(ctx, next) {
    if(ctx.data.code == 3){
      var eventModel = Transaction.app.models.Event;
      eventModel.create({"nom":"ZONA ABC"}, function(err, obj){
        //console.log('eventModel create', err);
      });
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: my answer was for you to point out that you needed to access the eventModel to get to the point of saving. Its good that it worked out, but you need to give credit as well.